# Android Studio- where the library classes are stored

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to know some facts about android studio.
If we use like this  `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'` in gradle file, then how/when android studio downloads the library and store it in where?

**Also how to change the default location of library download?**

Comment: it is in the local repo path

Comment: Prefferences->find sdk and there is tab "SDK Tools" and all this thing are stored in 'Android SDK Location: ...'

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The android default libraries like appcompact, design support libraries are stored in your folder where you have installed the SDK, precisely `<SDK FOLDER>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android` .
The 3rd party libraries are stored in `.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1` folder.
The gradle folder is hidden. In linux you can find it in your home directory by pressing `ctrl+h` which helps to view hidden files and folder.
In windows it is present at `C:\Users\UserName\.gradle`
e.g if you are using **butterknife** library then in above path there will be a folder get created as `com.getkeepsafe.relinker`, inside that folder you will find its related folders and files, `.aar` or `.jar` files.

Hopes this clears your question.

Answer (score 1):

From Android Studio, check the SDK location path like this:

```
File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location
```

Then navigate to that folder