# Android studio 3 cannot download repository (error: Failed to download SHA1 for resource)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

i use android studio version 3.0.0.

before update i use SDK manager for update support library. but after update android studio 3 i should update via `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/`. so i need support library 26.1.0.

on async gradle i have this error:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.

Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
Required by:
    project :app > com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1
 > Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
    > Failed to download SHA1 for resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
          > For input string: "<!"
```

why cannot download this: `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom` ?

i use proxy but cannot download.

this error is show for all dependencies library (appcampatv7, design, annonations and etc)

how to fix this **Failed to download SHA1 for resource** ?

UPDATE:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testtesttest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: `repositories {
       ....
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
     .....
    }`

Comment: `repositories {
   maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
   jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
}`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya this set on : `allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}`.

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya updated

Comment: looks like okay. Restart and sync project.

Comment: As Android Studio always Suggest to make the Gradle Implemented statement and the buildtool version code should be the same, Ty to make them same.

For some reason, if you don’t have the newest Gradle or the shortcut isn’t working for you, you can simply put the full path yourself:
`maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com'
}`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya not working. `Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0.

Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0.
Required by:
    project :app > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 > com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 > com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0
 > Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0.
    > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/1.0.0/runtime-1.0.0.pom`

Comment: Does this happen continuously?, or it's remain to this project only ?

Comment: @Ibrahim when update android studio from version 2 to 3. this errors happens

Comment: Well, I mean did you tried with other project or not, or it's happened continuously with all projects?

Comment: @Ibrahim i think should full unistall android studio with sdk and again install :|

Comment: @Ibrahim after update. i create new project for test. but happent this errors. i test invalidate and restart. i test proxy. but not working

Comment: Well, It should work with proxy(If you tried it correctly), if it's not working without it, I think you should file issue.

Comment: @Ibrahim I had to manual download from dl.google.com requred suppor library. location of support libraries in extra folder. but I do not know location of: `android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0`. can you say me location of this file for put after download manual.

Comment: support libraries downloaded to sdk, and other libraries to project folder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163015/android-studio-where-the-library-classes-are-stored

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fixed this problem after a lot of search. in `gradle.propertices` file set proxy both `http` and `https` and sync again.

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=12345
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1234m
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=12345
```