# Where are imported libraries stored in an android application?

Tags: android

I'm a newbie in android programming. Where in an android app are imported libraries stored? And also the libraries automatically imported by android studio on every android app.

Comment: Can refer here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163015/android-studio-where-the-library-classes-are-stored hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

in android studio libs are in this path

```
project level / .idea / libraries
```

in android apk libs are saved in

```
src/libs
```